# MongoDb update by replacing the document while using update operation ($currentDate)[pymongo]

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using pymongo in python
I have a mongodb document like this

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('55110d55a5bd910f2513fc91'), u'ghi': u'jkl'}
```

I want to update the document by replacing

```
db['table_name'].update({'ghi':'jkl'},{'ghio':'jkl'}, True)
```

The problem is that I wanted to use `$currentDate` along with the update query as I'm required to add update time with the document. How do I do that?

This is what I've tried out so far

```
db['table_name'].update({'ghi':'jkl'},{'$set':{'ghik':'jkl'}, '$currentDate':{'date':True}}, True)
```

The issue with the above code is that I do not want to use `$set` as it will retain the other fields which I do not require.

```
db['table_name'].update({'ghi':'jkl'},{'$set':{'ghik':'jkl'}, '$unset':{'ghi':True}, '$currentDate':{'date':True}}, True)
```

The above code works, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentDate` only works with update operators like `$set` and not with a full document update. You can use the `$unset` update as you pointed out, although this only wipes out fields you specifically name, you can set the timestamp clientside

```
db.test.update({ "ghi" : "jkl" }, { "ghio" : "jkl", "date" : datetime.today() })
```

or you can do two updates

```
db.test.update({ "ghi" : "jkl" }, { "ghio" : "jkl" })
db.test.update({ "ghio" : "jkl" }, { "$currentDate" : { "date" : true } })
```